# How to trigger on change when page is loaded form each parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a multiple table on a same page with country and country code, it's working fine, when page is loaded trigger on change is not working,

If india is selected country code should automatically should be select on load event
Here is my code

```
<table id="country">
      <tr>
        <td>
        <select class="country" name="country">
          <option value="">--select country--</option>
          <option selected value="1">India</option>
          <option value="2">China</option>
          <option value="3">Japan</option>
          <option value="4">Singapur</option>
        </select></td>
        <td>
          <select class="country_code" name="country_code">
            <option value="">--select code--</option>
            <option value="1">+91</option>
            <option value="2">+86</option>
            <option value="3">+81</option>
            <option value="4">+65</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <table id="country">
      <tr>
        <td>
        <select class="country" name="country">
          <option value="">--select country--</option>
          <option value="1">India</option>
          <option selected value="2">China</option>
          <option value="3">Japan</option>
          <option value="4">Singapur</option>
        </select></td>
        <td>
          <select class="country_code" name="country_code">
            <option value="">--select code--</option>
            <option value="1">+91</option>
            <option value="2">+86</option>
            <option value="3">+81</option>
            <option value="4">+65</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

My script file

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('table').on('change', '.country', function(){
          $(this).closest('td').parent().find('.country_code').val($(this).val());
        }).trigger('change');
    });
```

Comment: Id's should be unique to start with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `window .load()` event as it fires after the `DOM` and all the `HTML` has been loaded.

I changed all your tables `IDs` to `unique IDs` and changed the `names` on the fields as well so they don't duplicate.

Here is the code and the snippet at the bottom:

```js
$( window ).load(function()
{
    // Go through all tables on the page
    $( "table" ).each(function() 
    {
       // make strings like "#currentID .country"
       var thisCountry = "#" + $(this).attr('id').toString() + " .country";
       var thisCountryCode = "#" + $(this).attr('id').toString() + " .country_code";
       // assign the same selected value from country to country_code
       $( thisCountryCode )[0].selectedIndex = $( thisCountry )[0].selectedIndex;
    });
     
     
    // this is your original onchange handler
    $('table').on('change', '.country', function()
    {
       $(this).closest('td').parent().find('.country_code').val($(this).val());
    }).trigger('change');
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title of the document</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<table id="country1">
      <tr>
        <td>
        <select class="country" name="country1">
          <option value="">--select country--</option>
          <option selected value="1">India</option>
          <option value="2">China</option>
          <option value="3">Japan</option>
          <option value="4">Singapur</option>
        </select></td>
        <td>
          <select class="country_code" name="country_code2">
            <option value="">--select code--</option>
            <option value="1">+91</option>
            <option value="2">+86</option>
            <option value="3">+81</option>
            <option value="4">+65</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <table id="country2">
      <tr>
        <td>
        <select class="country" name="country2">
          <option value="">--select country--</option>
          <option value="1">India</option>
          <option selected value="2">China</option>
          <option value="3">Japan</option>
          <option value="4">Singapur</option>
        </select></td>
        <td>
          <select class="country_code" name="country_code2">
            <option value="">--select code--</option>
            <option value="1">+91</option>
            <option value="2">+86</option>
            <option value="3">+81</option>
            <option value="4">+65</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: when we can't use jquery trigger on this

Comment: Your tables `must` have different `IDs`. We then iterate through all tables and get their ID to identify their children (the two `<select>` by class). I don't understand why you can't use `jQuery this`.

Comment: @jvk can you explain what this means please: _when we can't use jquery trigger on this_, I think I didn't understand. I edited my answer to include your `onchange` function as well.